# How to hand headers in curl request in PowerShell windows

Tags: powershell, http, curl

```
curl -X POST <myUrl> -H "authorization: Bearer <valid token>"
```

But when I send it I get exception - Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the "authorization: Bearer " value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`curl` is aliased to the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet in Windows PowerShell.

As the error message indicates, the `-Headers` parameter of said cmdlet accepts a *dictionary* of header key-value pairs.

To pass an `Authorization` header, you'd do:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "<uri goes here>" -Method Post -Headers @{ Authorization = 'Bearer ...' } -UseBasicParsing
```

(Note that I'm explicitly passing the `-UseBasicParsing` switch - if not, Windows PowerShell will attempt to parse any HTML response with Internet Explorer's DOM rendering engine, which is probably not what you want in most cases)

---

If you need to pass headers with token-terminating characters (like `-`) in the name, qualify the key with `'` quotation marks:

```
$headers = @{ 
  'Authorization' = 'Bearer ...'
  'Content-Type'  = 'application/json'
}

Invoke-WebRequest ... -Headers $headers
```

If header *order* is important, make sure you desclare the dictionary literal `[ordered]`:

```
$headers = [ordered]@{ 
  'Authorization' = 'Bearer ...'
  'Content-Type'  = 'application/json'
}
```